# During implementing FIFO buffer code for serial communication taking too much time

Tags: fpga, fifo

I am a new bee in VHDL coding. I am currently working on starter kit spartan 3e. I have written a code for transmitting 5 bytes to PC and receiving 4 bytes. Now I have to add fifo buffer before transmitting and after receiving bytes.I have written code( taken from Pong P Chu) also but not working. Its taking too much time for synthesis. Please tell me where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```
entity fifo is
    generic ( 
         B : natural :=32; --------------------------------------------------- number of bits
        W : natural := 16 ----------------------------------------------------number of address bits
            );

    port ( ck       : in std_logic; ------------ clock
         reset       : in std_logic;
         rd          : in std_logic; -------- control signal for read 
         wr          : in std_logic; -------- control signal for write
        -- btn0             : in std_logic;
         write_data  : in std_logic_vector ( B-1 downto 0); ----------------------------data to be written in FIFO
         read_data   : out std_logic_vector ( B-1 downto 0) :=( others=> '0');------------------------------ data read from FIFO
         empty       : out std_logic; ------------ shows FIFO is empty, cannot be read
        full        : out std_logic ------------ shows FIFO is full, cannot be written
             );
    end fifo;

architecture arch4 of fifo is 

--------------state machines declared----------------------
    type reg_file_type is array (2**W - 1 downto 0) of std_logic_vector (B-1 downto 0);  --------------------array of 32 cross 32 for data
    signal array_reg : reg_file_type;
--------------------------------------------------------------------
----variables-------------------------------------------------------    

    --signal read_data     :  std_logic_vector ( B-1 downto 0); ------------------------------ data read from FIFO
    signal write_ptr_reg : std_logic_vector (W-1 downto 0); ----- addressing the data in fifo to write
    signal write_ptr_next: std_logic_vector (W-1 downto 0); ----- addressing next data in fifo to write
    signal write_ptr_succ : std_logic_vector (W-1 downto 0); ---- addressing next to next data in fifo to write

    signal read_ptr_reg : std_logic_vector (W-1 downto 0); ----- addressing the data in fifo to read
    signal read_ptr_next: std_logic_vector (W-1 downto 0); ----- addressing next data in fifo to read
    signal read_ptr_succ : std_logic_vector (W-1 downto 0); ---- addressing next to next data in fifo to read

    signal write_operation  : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0); ---- 00,01,10,11  only 00,01 and 10 are valid
    signal write_enable  : std_logic ;  ----------------  write enable
  -- signal rd          :  std_logic; -------- control signal for read 
  -- signal wr          :  std_logic; -------- control signal for write
   --signal empty       :  std_logic; ------------ shows FIFO is empty, cannot be read
    --signal full        :  std_logic ;------------ shows FIFO is full, cannot be written
   signal full_reg  : std_logic ;
    signal empty_reg : std_logic ;
    signal full_next   : std_logic ;
    signal empty_next   : std_logic ;
egin
------------------------------------------initialising register ------------------------------------------------------ 
 process (ck, reset)

 begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        array_reg <= ( others => (others=> '0'));   ---------------------initialsing
    else 
   if rising_edge(ck) then
        if write_enable ='1' then  
       --array_reg (std_logic_vector(write_ptr_reg)) <= write_data;
         array_reg (CONV_INTEGER( unsigned(write_ptr_reg))) <= write_data; -------------------------- directed towards address for writing data (first position)
         end if;
   end if;
 end if;
end process;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 --read_data <= array_reg (std_logic_vector(read_ptr_reg)) ;
 read_data <= array_reg (CONV_INTEGER( unsigned(read_ptr_reg))) ; ------ directed towards address for reading data (first position)
 write_enable <= wr and ( not full_reg );                       ------ write enabled only when FIFO is not full


 ---============================ control logic for fifo==================================================
 --------------------reading and writing process with  address pointers
 --======================================================================================================

process (ck, reset)

begin

    if (reset = '1') then
       write_ptr_reg <= (others => '0');
       read_ptr_reg <= (others => '0');
        full_reg <= '0';
        empty_reg <='1';
        else 
        if rising_edge(ck) then
           write_ptr_reg <= write_ptr_next; ---- control of pointers
            read_ptr_reg <= read_ptr_next;
            full_reg <= full_next;
            empty_reg <= empty_next;

        end if;
  end if;
end process;


------======================= successive pointer values update--=====================================

    write_ptr_succ <= std_logic_vector(( write_ptr_reg)+1);
    read_ptr_succ <= std_logic_vector ((read_ptr_reg)+1);


---==========main process for read write operation, shifting pointers and checking status of fifo ====================

write_operation <= wr & rd ;   ----- concatinating two signals so 10 or 01 is valid states


process (write_ptr_reg, write_ptr_succ, read_ptr_reg, read_ptr_succ,write_operation, empty_reg, full_reg)

begin

write_ptr_next <= write_ptr_reg;
read_ptr_next <= read_ptr_reg;
full_next <= full_reg;
empty_next <= empty_reg;

    case write_operation is 
      when "00" =>  
          ------------------------ wr =0 and read = 0 , no operation
      when "01" =>
      ----------------------------- wr =0 and read = 1 , read operation
     --if state_button = transit_pressed then        
          if (empty_reg /= '1') then  ----------------not empty
                read_ptr_next <= read_ptr_succ; ---- updating the address pointers
                full_next <= '0'; ------ clearing full status 
                if (read_ptr_succ = write_ptr_reg) then ---- checking the pointer positions whether equal
                    empty_next <= '1';
                end if;
         end if;
     -- end if;     
        when "10" => 
        ------------------------ wr =1 and read = 0, write operation
            if (full_reg /= '1') then ---------- not full
                 write_ptr_next <= write_ptr_succ;---- updating the address pointers
                  empty_next <= '0'; --- clearing empty status
                    if ( write_ptr_succ = read_ptr_reg) then  ------------- checking the pointer positions of successors to read pointer whether it is same or not
                     full_next <= '1';          -------------- fifo full only above condition is true
                end if;         
          end if;                    
       when others => 
    ------------------------------write and read i.e for 11
         write_ptr_next <= write_ptr_succ;
         read_ptr_next <= read_ptr_succ;

    end case;

end process;

----- updating the flag
full <= full_reg;
empty <= empty_reg;


end architecture arch4;
```

Comment: Perhaps, it's good to add the VHDL code, then it would be easier to others to know what is wrong?

Comment: Hi. I just edit the question with fifo code.

Answer (score 0):

The design is too big, it can't fit any [Spartan-3E](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds312.pdf) device even if all memory is mapped to Block RAMs. Indeed there are 2097152 flip-flops for `array_reg` signal.

```
2**W = 2**16 = 65536
65536*B = 65536*32 = 2097152
```

The size of the FIFO should be reduced and it's better to use Block RAMs instead of flip-flops. [Here](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com.tr/2011/01/block-and-distributed-rams-on-xilinx.html) is a RAM module in VHDL, which can be mapped to Block RAMs by Xilinx tools.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for making me understand better about the usage of memory. One more thing is, as explained in the link can I make use of the code and change the input length to 16 or 32 bit wide and depth 256. Then I can instantiate in my code( serial port) to save the data before transmitting to PC.

Comment: Yes, you can change the size and/or depth as long as there are enough resources on your FPGA. There is a better example [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_2/xst_v6s6.pdf), which is an official document by Xilinx. Starting from page 218, you can find dual-port RAM examples. Since everything is parametric, no need to change anything in the RAM module.

Comment: hi. I come across one more difficultly while instantiate the fifo code to my top module. I want to store some set of data say "WELCOME TO THE WORLD OF FPGA" then i want to retrieve it back say when button of fpga board is pressed or fifo is full then how I can implement this.

Comment: at present I am sending byte by byte and retrieving it. But bit confused regarding storing in fifo all recieved bytes and then at once displayed on terminal.if empty_tx ='1' then
       wr_tx <= '1';
       rd_tx <= '0';
       write_data_tx <= byte_1;
      end if; 
    if full_tx ='1'  then 
     wr_tx <= '0';
     rd_tx <= '1'; 
   end if;

Comment: You can also post a new question, it would be easier for you to define the problem. I'm on a travel now, maybe someone else can help before my return.

Comment: hi, hope you are back from travel. I have one more query in fifo implementation. Iimplemented the code like this  if rising_edge(ck) then
               if full_rx = '1' then 
                  we <= '0';
                  else 
                  we <= new_byte_in_buffer;
                end if;  
end if;               
     
if rising_edge(ck) then
     if (not empty_rx ='1') then                 
                  re <= '1' ;
      counts <= counts+ 1;
      else
                  re <= '0' ; 
                  counts <= 0;      
       end if;
        
end if;

Comment: I have a problem while reading data from fifo. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I'm looking at the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902141/fifo-implementation-vhdl) you posted. If I find something, I will write there.